# drupal content access error

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I have two pc, and installed two different version of xampp . one has php version of 5.3.x another has php version 5.4.4.
I am having problem with drupal's module named "content access". It works fine in the older version of xampp but shows error in the newer version.
here is the error

```
Notice: Undefined index: type in content_access_admin_settings_submit() (line 167 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mmg\mmgsecure\sites\all\modules\content_access\content_access.admin.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: type in content_access_admin_settings_submit() (line 181 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mmg\mmgsecure\sites\all\modules\content_access\content_access.admin.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: type in content_access_admin_settings_submit() (line 181 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mmg\mmgsecure\sites\all\modules\content_access\content_access.admin.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: type in content_access_admin_settings_submit() (line 181 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mmg\mmgsecure\sites\all\modules\content_access\content_access.admin.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: type in content_access_admin_settings_submit() (line 181 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mmg\mmgsecure\sites\all\modules\content_access\content_access.admin.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: type in content_access_admin_settings_submit() (line 181 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mmg\mmgsecure\sites\all\modules\content_access\content_access.admin.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: type in content_access_admin_settings_submit() (line 181 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mmg\mmgsecure\sites\all\modules\content_access\content_access.admin.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: type in content_access_admin_settings_submit() (line 181 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mmg\mmgsecure\sites\all\modules\content_access\content_access.admin.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: type in content_access_admin_settings_submit() (line 181 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mmg\mmgsecure\sites\all\modules\content_access\content_access.admin.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: type in content_access_admin_settings_submit() (line 181 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mmg\mmgsecure\sites\all\modules\content_access\content_access.admin.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: type in content_access_admin_settings_submit() (line 181 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mmg\mmgsecure\sites\all\modules\content_access\content_access.admin.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: type in content_access_admin_settings_submit() (line 181 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mmg\mmgsecure\sites\all\modules\content_access\content_access.admin.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: type in content_access_admin_settings_submit() (line 181 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mmg\mmgsecure\sites\all\modules\content_access\content_access.admin.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: edit any content in user_role_grant_permissions() (line 3041 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mmg\mmgsecure\modules\user\user.module).
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'module' cannot be null: INSERT INTO {role_permission} (rid, permission, module) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 3 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => edit any content [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => ) in user_role_grant_permissions() (line 3043 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mmg\mmgsecure\modules\user\user.module).
```

Can anyone help to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, this is the worst and you shouldn't actually do this for anything real, but on line 3046 of user.module, the function that makes the query for permissions gets defined. If you change

```
->fields(array(
    'module' => $modules[$name]
))
```

to

```
->fields(array(
    'module' => $module
))
```

Where you define $module (somewhere just before the `db_merge()` starts) as:

```
if (!empty($modules[$name])) {
  $module = $modules[$name];
}
else {
  $module = 'node'; // or features or whatever module you think is creating these permissions that aren't getting saved right
}
```

then I think your error will go away.

This is what is known as hacking core and you should never do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a helpful discussion about this issue
and a patch which worked for me at
https://drupal.org/comment/6573448#comment-6573448